# Regarding tree traversal

Tags: c++

Tried code for tree traversal but I'm not getting the expected output.

```
tree* insertion(int data)
{
 tree *ptr=new tree();
 ptr->data=data;
 ptr->left=NULL;
 ptr->right=NULL;
}
void preorder(tree* root)
{
if(root==NULL)
    return;
cout<<root->data<<" ";
preorder(root->left);
preorder(root->right);
}
void postorder(tree* root)
{
if(root==NULL)
    return;
preorder(root->left);
preorder(root->right);
cout<<root->data<<" ";
}
void inorder(tree* root)
{
if(root==NULL)
    return;
preorder(root->left);
cout<<root->data<<" ";
preorder(root->right);
}
```

expected output: (a) Inorder (Left, Root, Right) : 4 2 5 1 3
(b) Preorder (Root, Left, Right) : 1 2 4 5 3
(c) Postorder (Left, Right, Root) : 4 5 2 3 1

My output: Preorder traversal : 1 2 4 5 3
Postorder traversal : 2 4 5 3 1
Inorder traversal : 2 4 5 1 3

Comment: The function insertion returns nothing.:)

Comment: You should be more careful when you use copy/paste programming.

Comment: `tree* insertion(int data)` -- Looking for the `return ptr;` in that function...looking...looking...can't find it.  Undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every recursive function you call `preorder` and not the correct function. (In `inorder` you should call `inorder` and in `postorder` call `postorder`

EDIT: I see that the function insertion is of type tree* but returns nothing; maybe you forgot a `return ptr`

Comment: Thank you for helping it was a copy-paste mistake